What does “formerly held to” mean?
What does "formerly held to" mean exactly? Does it mean it used to be a certain way, but it's no longer the case? Does "to hold" in this case mean "to maintain in a given condition, situation, or action"? Thank you !
"Succubus: an imaginary demon assuming female form and formerly held to have sexual intercourse with men in their sleep."

formerly held to be... = in the past, was believed / asserted to be... It's a sightly "strong" way of putting it - they could have said thought, believed, or even claimed with less force. But metaphorical "positions held" implies unbending assertion that admits no debate. Probably intended as a sideswipe at the medieval Catholic church, whose Inquisition used such nonsense to justify appalling persecution of anyone they might almost randomly accuse of consorting with the Devil.

I add to what @FumbleFingers said.
Hold to is explained in sense 14, part three of Collins Dictionary's definition for hold:

verb
If you say that you hold to a particular opinion or belief, you are stating firmly that you continue to have that opinion or belief.
[formal]
I hold to my belief that people should be allowed to have private lives. [VERB to noun]

This interpretation is consistent with that in Cambridge Dictionary:

a female evil spirit who is believed to have sex with men while they are sleeping


Thomas Jefferson began the U.S. Declaration of Independence with the words, “We hold these truths to be self-evident…”

There isn't a missing to - it's quite correct that there's only one.You can hold to a position/belief OR you can hold a position/belief with no preposition, but you can't hold to to a position/belief. with two prepositions..

Thanks, @FumbleFingers.  I've corrected my answer.
